# .htaccess rewrite rule for anything except specific http_host

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

### Context of the problem:

I'm using shared hosting via cPanel, and on my current hosting setup I don't have the ability to create additional virtual hosts. Presently to keep costs down I am trying to avoid more complexity, so I have several sites symlinked in to public_html

```
 public_html /
 |
 |---> siteone.net /
 |
 |---> sitetwo.com /
 |
 |---> sitethree.net.au /
 |
 |--  (etc)
```

.

### The Problem:

'sitetwo.com' is accessible from siteone.net as http://siteone.net/sitetwo.com/

.

### Aim for Solution:

My goal is to prevent access to the site folders for the other sites. I'm only simulating virtual hosts which is clearly not ideal, but I need to do it for a few more months.

*NB: Currently domains are routed using htaccess code as follows:*

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?siteone.net$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/siteone/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /siteone/$1
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?siteone.net$
 RewriteRule ^(/)?$ siteone/index.php [L]
```

.

### Attempted Solution:

My aim was to redirect anything that was not routed via siteone.com one to 404:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?siteone.net$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/siteone.net/
 RewriteRule -- serve 404 page ----- [L]
```

This did not work.  The mod_rewrite manual and google don't seem to think that NOT logic is available against HTTP_HOST in a rewrite condition...  or else I'm not reading it right.

Any assistance will be gratefully received.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `/siteone.net/` folder as well?
`

Comment: potentially... not always

Comment: Didn't get your comment, what do you mean?

Comment: You asked if I have a .htaccess file in /siteone.net/ (not it's real name).  So yes - 'siteone' has a .htaccess file, but sitetwo might not. It's up to me.  There's no specific reason that I know of that would compel me in either direction... unless you have one.

Comment: ok check answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok add this code as first rule in `/siteone.net/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?siteone\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

**Optionally if .htaccess doesn't exist for `sitetwo.com` then use:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?sitetwo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitetwo\.com/ - [NC,F]
```

Comment: Thanks! I shall try this out shortly